# How move caret to the end of line

Tags: bash, prompt

I want to add colors and git branch name to terminal.
I added PS1 in `.bashrc` 
[image]
but has an issue

in folders without git everything works fine, but where git is caret goes to the beginnings of the line and all new text types above initial string
[image]

It is already saved in LF line separator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape sequences (e.g. the ones changing the color) need to be enclosed between `\[` and `\]` in PS1. See the section "PROMPTING" in bash's manual.

Comment: you are right again))) thanks